# How can you download a file/zip from the commandline using putty?

Tags: cmd, putty, 7zip

I'm trying to write a batch script (CMD @ Windows XP Pro) that will automatically download and unzip packages with the help of 7zip and putty/psftp

If I have a URL to a package to download http://somesite.org/packages/package.zip how do I download it on command line using putty?

Also if you have a better way to do this that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

wget is of course an obvious solution, but I also suggest to have a look at [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/).  From their website:

> curl is a command line tool for
>   transferring files with URL syntax,
>   supporting FTP, FTPS, HTTP, HTTPS,
>   SCP, SFTP, TFTP, TELNET, DICT, LDAP,
>   LDAPS and FILE. curl supports SSL
>   certificates, HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, FTP
>   uploading, HTTP form based upload,
>   proxies, cookies, user+password
>   authentication (Basic, Digest, NTLM,
>   Negotiate, kerberos...), file transfer
>   resume, proxy tunneling and a busload
>   of other useful tricks.

Of course free and open source, and despite its huge list of supported protocols it's as simple to use as wget, so to use your example

```
curl -O http://somesite.org/packages/package.zip
```

downloads package.zip to a local file with the same name

```
curl -o myname.zip http://somesite.org/packages/package.zip
```

downloads package.zip as myname.zip

```
curl http://somesite.org/packages/package.zip > package.zip
```

redirects curl's stdout to package.zip

EDIT - example corrected, with thanks to @PrabhakarKasi

Comment: +1 for curl. Those of us that use linux/unix often are prone to use what we know, but that doesn't always mean it's the best solution for windows environments.

Comment: @Stefan cURL exists under Linux/Unix too, in fact I started using it under HP/UX to solve some hard-to-shellscript ftp exchange problems.  Afterwards I discovered that it also existed for Windows :-)

Answer (score 2):

win32 version of wget:

http://pages.interlog.com/~tcharron/wgetwin.html

Answer (score 2):

Putty isn't really a download tool. Unless you want to download something via SCP/SFTP. So yes, [`wget`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) is more helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know putty, but certainly wget can do. If you are in Windows, you can get it by cygwin or just google a win32 version.

Answer (score 0):

pscp.exe -pw yourpassword you@somesite.org:/packages/package.zip .\

The path to /packages/package.zip should be whatever the path to the public web files are on the server. So, for example, on some old apache server, it might be:

pscp.exe -pw yourpassword you@somesite.org:/users/httpd/vhosts/default/packages/package.zip .\

Answer (score 0):

Use pscp, which comes with PuTTY:

```
pscp user@host:/path/to/file.7z .
7z e file.7z
```

If you set this up with SSH [keys](http://www.howtoforge.com/ssh_key_based_logins_putty), pscp won't have to ask you for a password.